# How do I add outward pointing arrows to the \thicksim math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I am in need of a symbol that looks like `\thicksim`, but with outward pointing arrows at each side. Is there a package I can use to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `\newcommand\dirsim{\mathrel{\leftarrow\!\thicksim\!\rightarrow}}`?  Or `\newcommand\dirsim{\mathrel{\prec\mkern-4mu\thicksim\mkern-4mu\succ}}`?

Comment: Here is a visual of each of @StevenB.Segletes's suggestions: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvvxq.png)

Comment: Thank you Steven and Werner. This approximates the effect I am looking for. Is there a way to, rather than joining the symbols, convert the endings of the \thicksim into arrows without having to get down to Metafont tweaking?

Comment: Very few fonts are directly generated from metafont these days almost al uses use scalable type1 versions

Comment: [you could use  this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LIes.png) `\leftrightsquigglearrow` from the stix package (also in amssymb, but the ams one is more jagged)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can to propose a suitably rotated of the standard symbol into the `MnSymbol` package called `\squigarrownwse` (with two variants using or only `\rotatebox` or `\rotatebox+\reflectbox`) that has the arrows both on the left and on the right as in the attached image and it could probably be a symbol that you like. You can determine the blanks you want either by inserting `\,` or by omitting those blanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\squisimm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\squigarrownwse$}}
\newcommand{\squisim}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\reflectbox{$\squigarrownwse$}}}

\begin{document}
$f(x)\squisim\, g(x), \quad \psi(x)\squisimm\, \varphi(x)$
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:** Surely this code is better than the previous because with `fdsymbol` package the arrows are horizontal and not inclined.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}%%%%%%%%% <----------I prefer this package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\horsquigarrow}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\updownsquigarrow$}}
\begin{document}
\noindent Peraphs this is a better symbol because the arrows are horizontal and not inclined: see example below. 
\begin{equation}
    \lambda \horsquigarrow \mu, \quad  \text{ other symbol}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Other image:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Sebastiano, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @SantiagoNuñez-Corrales Hi, I have very happy to help you :-) :-)

Comment: That is a very nice adaptation!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes So I become emotioned...:-)